# How to print only a value in key value pair

Tags: ruby

This is my code

```
lunch_order = {
  "Ryan" => "wonton soup",
  "Eric" => "hamburger",
  "Jimmy" => "sandwich",
  "Sasha" => "salad",
  "Cole" => "taco"
}

lunch_order.each { |element| puts element }
```

I want the value to be printed out, but here, both the value and the key are printed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
lunch_order.each { |key, value| puts value}
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/B6rG8V8C)

Comment: You could write the block variables as `|_,value|` or `|_key,value|` to draw attention to the fact that you are not using the key in the block.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the values only with [each_value](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-each_value)

> ```
> h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
> h.each_value {|value| puts value }
> ```

You can read more about api of hash [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html).

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to do it in Ruby:

```
lunch_order.values.each { |element| puts element }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby a hash contains **Keys** and **Values**. So in your case the keys are:

**Keys**

- Ryan
- Eric
- Jimmy
- Sasha
- Cole

And the Values for those keys are:

**Values**

- Wonton Soup
- Hamburger
- Sandwich
- Salad
- Taco

And all you'd need to do to call the values is use the each loops like you've done but instead of using element as the local variable within the block, you use something like this:

```
lunch_order.each do { |key, value| puts value }
```

Comment: Strike do. What does this add to DickieBoy's earlier answer?

Comment: In Ruby there are 2 ways of declaring a block. You can either use do or end or you can use brackets. This can be made even simpler if you eliminate the do word. Less space means less code.

Comment: Yes, @DarkMouse, but you can't have `do` without `end`, and you can't have both `do..end` and brackets. Joe's line above raises a syntax error.  He needs to remove `do` or remove the brackets and add `end`.

Answer (score 0):

`lunch_order.each_pair { |key,value| puts value }`

Docs: http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/each_pair

Comment: Dickie, I see Brutus has earned `+2` by replacing your `each_pair` with `each`, while you are still languishing with `0`.  Life is unfair!

Answer (score 0):

Given your original code

```
lunch_order = {
  "Ryan" => "wonton soup",
  "Eric" => "hamburger",
  "Jimmy" => "sandwich",
  "Sasha" => "salad",
  "Cole" => "taco"
}
```

You created a hash, which consists of both keys and values. Keys are on the left, values on the right. To get only the values use

```
lunch_order.values.each{|value| puts value}
```

Hope this helps.